# Correct Approach for Testing class having no default contructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, refactoring

Below is `DBMetaData` class dependent on `TableData` :

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;    
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DBMetaData {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private Map<String, TableData> tables;
    private static final String[] TYPES = {"TABLE", "VIEW"};

    public DBMetaData(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.tables = new HashMap<String, TableData>();
    }
.......

}


public class TableData {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, ColumnData> columns = new HashMap<String, ColumnData>();
    private String catalog;
    private String schema; 

    TableData(ResultSet rs, DatabaseMetaData meta) throws SQLException {
    catalog = rs.getString("TABLE_CAT");
    schema = rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM");
    name = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
    initColumns(meta);
    }
.......
}
```

How to write test case of these class as both of them is not having a parameter-less Constructor.
As per my understanding :

> 1. Either I have to write a parameter-less constructor,or
> 2. Test by using Reflection.

I am not able to understand what should i use from the above two approach.

- Which one is better architecturally and as per oops Concept ?
- Is there any other possibility than above two ?
- Is there any reference or resource to write test cases by refactoring
  such type of codes ?

Comment: You don't _write_ a default constructor. You write a parameter-less constructor or you let the compiler provide you with a default constructor.

Comment: In this case you can not use the default constructor, because you have already created constructors for the classes. You could create parameter-less contructors like Sotirios mentioned to test your classes

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You call the constructor with the arguments you want in your test, and now you call the method you want to test. Why would you need a no-arg constructor?

Comment: other wise i have to pass DataSource instance to the class...i dont know actually how to write test cases.So i m bit stuck here.I dont know which approach is better.It will be g8 if u can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think a parameterless constructor is needed for testing.  It is not.

the parameters in your constructors are *dependencies* and your unit tests should mock these dependencies so you can test all possible variations that these dependencies can have that would affect your class under test.

For example, `TableData` takes a `ResultSet`.  You should have a test that checks to make sure your `TableData` object works correctly if it is constructed with an empty resultset (no rows).

There are several Mock object libraries for java, the 2 most popular are [EasyMock](http://easymock.org) and [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

The syntax for these libraires is slightly different but in pseudocode here's how you would test with an empty  ResultSet.

```
//NOTE: Pseduocode, will not compile just meant to give you an idea how it works
@Test
public void emptyResultSet(){

     DataBaseMetaData metadata = ...
     ResultSet emptyResultSet = createMock(ResultSet.class);

     //tell the mock to return false when it's next() method is called.
     //this means there are no rows
     when(emptyResultSet.next()).return(false);

     //cut = Class Under Test
     TableData cut = new TableData(emptyResultSet, metadata);
     //assertions go here
```

Comment: This appears to answer the specific question regarding the OP's code.  But supposing `TableData` were a dependency you needed to mock in order to use it with another C.U.T.?  I venture to suggest that this is what the OP might have been asking about... (and why I ended up here...)